# Proving a limit by definition in the multivariable case

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am doing my first steps in this subject and I am trying to understand the following:

So we use the same definition as the single variable case, just that the distance (absolute value) is now replaced with norm.

For all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $||(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-(p_1,p_2,...,p_n)||<\delta$ then $||f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-f(l_{1},l_2,...l_n)||<\epsilon$

But because we are in the euclidean space and we have a scalar function, can we always assume that $||f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-f(l_{1},l_2,...l_n)||<\epsilon\iff |f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-f(l_{1},l_2,...l_n)|<\epsilon$
Or in other words, we can always look at the morm of between function and the limit point as an absolute value?

And if for example we have to prove by definition: $$lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

We can immediately with $|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0|$?

And then:

$|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0|\leq \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{|x||y|}{|x|}=|y|=\sqrt{y^2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon$

So it is sufficient to  take $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: @StackTD maybe in a case the we are not in the euclidean space with the euclidean norm?

Comment: Indeed; which is why I already deleted my comment.

Comment: @StackTD sorry you were fast

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Euclidean distance for the norm, then it doesn't matter, since for $\vec x = (x)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $\| \vec x \| = \| (x) \| = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. In that case, the norm usually isn't used in the definition but simply the absolute value (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_more_than_one_variable) for example).